# What is the problem with my else if statements?

Tags: java, if-statement

**Purpose of this code:** Find the lowest integer inserted by a user.

**Problem facing:** When the variable `thirdInt` is supposed to be the lowest number, the console doesn't print out the result.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with that part of my code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindMinimum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the first integer:");
        int firstInt = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the second integer:");
        int secondInt = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the third integer:");
        int thirdInt = input.nextInt();

        if(firstInt<secondInt || firstInt == secondInt) {
            if(firstInt<thirdInt || firstInt == thirdInt) {
                System.out.println("The minimum is " + firstInt);    
            }  
        }
        else if(secondInt<firstInt || secondInt == firstInt) {
            if(secondInt<thirdInt || secondInt == thirdInt) {
                System.out.println("The minimum is " + secondInt);    
            }
        }
        else if(thirdInt<firstInt || thirdInt == firstInt) {
            if(thirdInt<secondInt || thirdInt == secondInt) {
                System.out.println("The minimum is " + thirdInt);    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly to make it readable.

Comment: Consider using a loop to do this and a single variable to hold the minimum value.

Comment: Let's consider stepping though this program with the values 5,10,3. Is the first value less than the second (is 5<10)? Yes. Is the first value less than the third (is 5<3)? No. The program ends here. It is true that at this point we would know that if first<second and third<first, that the third value is the smallest, but there is no print statement for that. The else ifs would not run because the first if statement was true.

Comment: Also, you should really close that scanner so that you don't have a memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

The answer can be very simple like the following (Like what [Matthew0898](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4241932/matthew0898) had said in the comment)

```
int answer = firstInt;

if secondInt < answer {
   answer = secondInt;
}

if thirdInt < answer {
   answer = thirdInt;
}

System.out.println("The minimum is " + answer);
```

Comment: I accidentally hit delete on the comment in question. I attempted to recreate the post.

Comment: @Matthew0898 said that it can be done as if you are following the variables from the first to the third with comparison to get select the lowest one. Just like a walk down. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check what you have done with you first two outer `if` statements:

- The first one: `if(firstInt<secondInt ...)`
- The second one: `else if((secondInt<firstInt ...)`

The only way for anything to be passed down to the third `if` statement is if `firstInt==secondInt`, which was also eliminated by your `|| secondInt == firstInt`.

Rather than what you had, you probably want something like:

```
if(firstInt <= secondInt && firstInt <= thirdInt)
{
    System.out.println("The minimum is " + firstInt);    
} 
else if(secondInt <= thirdInt)
{
    System.out.println("The minimum is " + secondInt);    
} 
else
{
    System.out.println("The minimum is " + thirdInt);    
}
```